# Slope stability using the Riemann-Roch theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying about the (Stability on a curve). Suppose $C$ is a smooth curve of genus g. The Riemann-Roch
theorem asserts that if $E$ is a coherent sheaf on $C$ then the Euler characteristic of $E $ is $\chi(E)= deg(E)+ r(E)(1-g)$

Polarizing $C$ with $H = p$ a point, we find

Then The Hilbert polynomial    $P(E,m)= \chi(E(m))$  $=deg(E(m))+r(E)(1-g)$.

My question is how can we rewrite these equation to become  $r(E)m +(deg(E)+r(E)(1-g))$?

Comment: Please, are there any help

Comment: What do you mean by $E(m)$?

Comment: By the definition of the Hilbert polynomial m is polynomial

Comment: Please if any one know any thing in this topic just give me a hint, who these equations are equal

Comment: E(m) is the twisted sheaf